# How can I install windows 10 on a separate SSD on legacy boot?

Tags: debian, windows, multi-boot

I have Debian 11 installed and want to install windows 10 onto the other SSD in my system so I can play windows exclusives, but my Linux installation is in legacy boot, so I know I can't install windows into the same SSD. Is it possible to install windows onto the other SSD without having to change my Debian installation?

Comment: Have you seen dual-boot on separate SSD's at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033497/dual-boot-windows-10-and-linux-ubuntu-on-separate-ssd ?

Comment: **Even if you were to install Windows on the other SSD you would still have to disable Legacy boot in order to boot into Windows.** "Is it possible to install windows onto the other SSD without having to change my Debian installation?" - No; Because Windows 11 does not support Legacy Boot and Windows does not support booting into UEFI mode while legacy mode is enabled.

Comment: Windows 10 should be fine with legacy boot